# Vagrantbox is missing hard drive?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, hard-drive

I created completely new vagrant box (with bionic server installation) for VirtualBox with VDI hard disk type of 60gb.

Everything else seems the be working fine, but I get only 4gb of HDD in vagrant box.

Any idea what might cause the issue?

`Usage of /:   91.1% of 3.87GB` when I login with `vagrant ssh`.

`df -h`

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               463M     0  463M   0% /dev
tmpfs                               99M  992K   98M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  3.6G  136M  97% /
tmpfs                              493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop1                          90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8039
/dev/sda2                          976M   89M  820M  10% /boot
```

`$ sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 60 GiB, 64424509440 bytes, 125829120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 70F42037-B7D6-4DDB-AC56-9CE5DDFBA29B
```

Is the custom box completely doomed or can it be saved still?

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the ouput of following command?

```
sudo lsblk
```

You are using LVM in your disk.

[LVM HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/)